# How do I get the coordinate of a specific number in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, tuples

If I have a matrix say

```
grid = np.array([ 
[0,2,1,0],
[0,1,0,-1]])
```

how do I call the specific coordinates of a number?
If I wanted to call for 2 and then assign the coordinates of 2 to an variable

```
start = np.where(grid==2) ## I want to assign my start point to 2 
start =start.index ## but actually I want to only use the coordinates of the point, so (0,1)

goal = np.where(grid==-1) 
goal = goal.index ## I want my code to realize the goal is actually (1,3)
```

Comment: How is your current code different than what you want? I would do it just like that...

Comment: You can use `start, = np.argwhere(grid==2)`. Be sure to notice the comma after `start`. This will raise an exception if there are multiple or no `2`s in `grid`.

Comment: Either you're expecting `(1,2)` for `2` and `(2,4)` for `-1`, or `(0,1)` for `2` and `(1,3)` for `-1`, I'd think? I.e. not `(0,2)` and `(1,4)`. Otherwise, why would you expect the first dimension to start at `0` and the second to start at `1`?

Comment: @JETM later on in my code when Im finding the heuristic  it gives me an exception at the gscore: 'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
and this doesn't happen when I assign start = (0,0) goal = (1,4)

  def heuristic(a, b):
    return np.sqrt((b[0] - a[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - a[1]) ** 2)
 
#f#finding shortest path
def astar(array, start, goal):
    neighbors = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]
    close_set = set()
    came_from = {}
    gscore = {start:0} 
    fscore = {start:heuristic(start, goal)}
    oheap = []
    heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[start], start))

Comment: @Grismar I meant (0,1) and (1,3)

Answer (score 1):

What were you trying to achieve with `start.index`?  `start` is a tuple of arrays, and as such does have a `index` method.  But `start.index` just returns that method; it doesn't evaluate it.

But lets look at what `where` produces:

```
In [123]: np.where(grid==2)
Out[123]: (array([0]), array([1]))
```

This tuple can be used as an index:

```
In [124]: grid[np.where(grid==2)]
Out[124]: array([2])
```

For a value that has several occurrences:

```
In [125]: np.where(grid==0)
Out[125]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 3, 0, 2]))
In [126]: grid[np.where(grid==0)]
Out[126]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

For `grid==3`, the result would be a tuple of 0d arrays.

`argwhere` applies `transpose` to that result, producing a 2d array:

```
In [127]: np.argwhere(grid==2)
Out[127]: array([[0, 1]])
In [128]: np.argwhere(grid==0)
Out[128]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

As a group that array can't be used to index the points, but individual rows provide coordinates of an element.

Paul Panzer suggested using `unpacking` to test if it only finds one value:

```
In [129]: index, = np.argwhere(grid==2)
In [130]: index
Out[130]: array([0, 1])
```

It raises an error if there are more than one, or none:

```
In [131]: index, = np.argwhere(grid==0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-633b3ba6cf90> in <module>
----> 1 index, = np.argwhere(grid==0)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
In [132]: index, = np.argwhere(grid==3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-d87481a3069b> in <module>
----> 1 index, = np.argwhere(grid==3)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
```

All of these provide the coordinates of a point (if it exists).  There are various ways of extracting them from the result(s), depending on what you need to do with  them.

---

Code in comments isn't very readable.  As you can see my guess as to how it should be indented is probably wrong:

```
start = (0,0)
goal = (1,4)
def heuristic(a, b):
    return np.sqrt((b[0] - a[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - a[1]) ** 2) #f
#finding shortest path 
def astar(array, start, goal):
    neighbors = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)] 
    close_set = set() 
    came_from = {} 
    gscore = {start:0} 
    fscore = {start:heuristic(start, goal)} 
    oheap = [] 
    heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[start], start))
```

`'unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` error means you trying to use an array as key for a dictionary, or an entry in a set.  A tuple like `(0,0)` can be used as key or in a set.

You many have to convert an array into a tuple.

```
In [133]: set([(0,0)])
Out[133]: {(0, 0)}
In [134]: set([[0,0]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-47c07050cf89> in <module>
----> 1 set([[0,0]])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
In [135]: set([tuple([0,0])])
Out[135]: {(0, 0)}
In [136]: set([np.array([0,0])])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-ecc6d46e403b> in <module>
----> 1 set([np.array([0,0])])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
In [137]: set([tuple(np.array([0,0]).tolist())])
Out[137]: {(0, 0)}
```

Comment: To get tuple instead of array: `coords, = zip(*np.where(grid==2))`

Answer (score 0):

This should give ya what you need. You probably want to add 1 to the first coordinate as well if you don't want your arrays to start at 0.

```
import numpy as np


grid = np.array([ 
[0,2,1,0],
[0,1,0,-1]])

coord = np.where(grid == 2)
# Grab x axis coordinates with coord[0][0]
# Add 1 t y axis to resemble coordinates more
coord_to_set = (coord[0][0], coord[1][0] + 1)

# prints (0,2)
print(str(coord_to_set))
```

Comment: I would for the coordinates to be grabbed automatically though, so if I ever change the location of the 2 it finds the coordinates by itself @Chris Alderson

Answer (score 0):

### Task definition: assign all found <sub>principally `{0+}`</sub>locations into a variable

Let's create a trivial working data into a **`grid`**:

```
>>> grid = np.arange( 25 ).reshape( ( 5, 5 ) )
>>> grid
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

make the monotonic data "noisy" to also repeat some values

```
>>> grid += np.random.randint( -1, 1, ( 5, 5 )  )
>>> grid
array([[ 0,  0,  2,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  6,  8,  8],
       [10, 10, 12, 13, 13],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 19],
       [20, 20, 21, 22, 24]])
```

find all locations and assign 'em to a variable **`aResult`** for a few test-cases:

```
>>> _ = np.where( grid == 0 )
>>> aResult = [ (_[0][i]+1, _[1][i]+1) for i in range( len( _[0] ) ) ] if _[0].shape[0] > 0 else []; aResult

[(1, 1), (1, 2)]

>>> _ = np.where( grid == 20 );
>>> aResult = [ (_[0][i]+1, _[1][i]+1) for i in range( len( _[0] ) ) ] if _[0].shape[0] > 0 else []; aResult

[(5, 1), (5, 2)]

>>> _ = np.where( grid == -123456789 );
>>> aResult = [ (_[0][i]+1, _[1][i]+1) for i in range( len( _[0] ) ) ] if _[0].shape[0] > 0 else []; aResult

[]

>>> _ = np.where( grid > 5 );
>>> aResult = [ (_[0][i]+1, _[1][i]+1) for i in range( len( _[0] ) ) ] if _[0].shape[0] > 0 else []; aResult

[(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5)]
```

A `list`-representation of all, properly located `( row, column )`-tuples, as was requested, in `aResult` was chosen just for an example and could be any other, more feasible for further processing.

---

### Finally :

> Q: *How do I get the coordinate of a specific number in an **array** in python?*

As all of you have already expected:

```
>>> np.array( aResult )
array([[2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 5],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [5, 3],
       [5, 4],
       [5, 5]])
```